# Set iOS device to sleep, but not lock

Tags: ios

Is it possible to set an iOS device screen not to lock, but rather just after a preset time of in activity on the sleep and be taken out of sleep, by either :

- touching the screen
- receiving a notification

(both without having to press the on / off or home button)

Comment: Do you mean other than setting `Auto-Lock` to 'Never'?  I'm a bit confused by what you're asking.

Comment: @fsb , setting auto lock - never, stops the screen from going to sleep, i woulds still like the screen to go to sleep, but just not lock so that the screen could be woken by just touching the screen

Comment: There's no way to do that on a non-jailbroken iPhone.  You'd have to manually darken the screen to black each time and then leave the auto-lock to 'never', I don't think that's what you're looking for.